# Blank screen after sleeping: hotplug event: connector link-state is BAD

Tags: arch-linux, laptop, monitors, hot-plug

In the past my laptop worked well, but for the past months I have had issues with the laptop screen not being able to wake up after certain events. Basically, after I suspend the laptop there is an estimated 15% of the time that the screen will not turn on after I wake the machine. A similar percentage of blank screens appears when the screen goes black after a period of non-activity. When I move the mouse, it may or may not wake up again.

I reviewed one of those instances in which the screen doesn't turn on after it has gone black due to non-activity (because there are less log entries than with a suspend). During the period that the screen went black and I moved the mouse again there were no journalctl entries. However, in the xorg log I found this (I can't decipher the timestamps but this is the end of the log file):

```
[    45.238] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.238] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    45.239] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[    45.239] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[    45.239] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    45.239] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    45.239] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[    45.240] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    45.240] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    45.241] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[    45.241] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    45.241] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  6116.285] (WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 58's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this fails...
[  6116.296] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4963
[  6116.296] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  6116.296] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[  6116.296] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  111.02  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (53.4 kHz e)
[  7335.277] (II) event10 - Genius USB Optical Mouse: Enabling spurious button debouncing, see https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.11.1/button_debouncing.html for details
[ 12686.324] (WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 58's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this fails...
[ 12686.335] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4963
[ 12686.335] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 12686.335] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.78  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[ 12686.335] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  111.02  1920 1966 1996 2080  1080 1082 1086 1112 +hsync -vsync (53.4 kHz e)
[ 13421.811] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 13421.811] (EE) systemd-logind disappeared (stopped/restarted?)
[ 13421.811] (EE) 
[ 13421.811] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 13421.811] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/george/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 13421.811] (EE) 
[ 13421.811] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 13421.811] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[ 13421.811] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[ 13421.811] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
[ 13421.813] (EE) systemd-logind: ReleaseControl failed: Connection was disconnected before a reply was received
[ 13421.813] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

What stands out is:

```
[ 12686.324] (WW) modeset(0): hotplug event: connector 58's link-state is BAD, tried resetting the current mode. You may be leftwith a black screen if this fails...
```

Using intel915 graphics card

```
$ lcpci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics (rev 08)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)

# systool -m i915 -av
Module = "i915"

  Attributes:
    coresize            = "1941504"
    initsize            = "0"
    initstate           = "live"
    refcnt              = "5"
    srcversion          = "49ACDCA7EE082E3C46EE9EB"
    taint               = ""
    uevent              = <store method only>

  Parameters:
    alpha_support       = "Y"
    disable_display     = "N"
    disable_power_well  = "1"
    edp_vswing          = "0"
    enable_cmd_parser   = "Y"
    enable_dc           = "-1"
    enable_dp_mst       = "Y"
    enable_dpcd_backlight= "N"
    enable_execlists    = "1"
    enable_fbc          = "1"
    enable_guc_loading  = "0"
    enable_guc_submission= "0"
    enable_gvt          = "N"
    enable_hangcheck    = "Y"
    enable_ips          = "1"
    enable_ppgtt        = "3"
    enable_psr          = "0"
    enable_rc6          = "1"
    error_capture       = "Y"
    fastboot            = "N"
    force_reset_modeset_test= "N"
    guc_firmware_path   = "(null)"
    guc_log_level       = "-1"
    huc_firmware_path   = "(null)"
    inject_load_failure = "0"
    invert_brightness   = "0"
    load_detect_test    = "N"
    lvds_channel_mode   = "0"
    lvds_use_ssc        = "-1"
    mmio_debug          = "0"
    modeset             = "-1"
    nuclear_pageflip    = "N"
    panel_ignore_lid    = "1"
    prefault_disable    = "N"
    reset               = "2"
    semaphores          = "0"
    use_mmio_flip       = "0"
    vbt_firmware        = "(null)"
    vbt_sdvo_panel_type = "-1"
    verbose_state_checks= "Y"

  Sections:
    .altinstr_aux       = "0xffffffffc0c126ae"
    .altinstr_replacement= "0xffffffffc0c12135"
    .altinstructions    = "0xffffffffc0c55678"
    .bss                = "0xffffffffc0cbe680"
    .data..cacheline_aligned= "0xffffffffc0cbdc80"
    .data..read_mostly  = "0xffffffffc0cbb980"
    .data.unlikely      = "0xffffffffc0cbb918"
    .data               = "0xffffffffc0cb0b40"
    .exit.text          = "0xffffffffc0c126f6"
    .fixup              = "0xffffffffc0c1270d"
    .gnu.linkonce.this_module= "0xffffffffc0cbe340"
    .init.text          = "0xffffffffc0a9f000"
    .note.gnu.build-id  = "0xffffffffc0c13000"
    .orc_unwind         = "0xffffffffc0c76c14"
    .orc_unwind_ip      = "0xffffffffc0c55b58"
    .parainstructions   = "0xffffffffc0c47a30"
    .ref.data           = "0xffffffffc0cbbbe0"
    .rodata             = "0xffffffffc0c130a0"
    .rodata.str1.1      = "0xffffffffc0c48c7c"
    .rodata.str1.8      = "0xffffffffc0c2bb00"
    .smp_locks          = "0xffffffffc0c54f88"
    .strtab             = "0xffffffffc0ac5e28"
    .symtab             = "0xffffffffc0aa1000"
    .text..refcount     = "0xffffffffc0c122a5"
    .text               = "0xffffffffc0b1f000"
    .text.unlikely      = "0xffffffffc0c0abbc"
    __bug_table         = "0xffffffffc0cb8e10"
    __ex_table          = "0xffffffffc0cadbf0"
    __jump_table        = "0xffffffffc0cb0000"
    __kcrctab_gpl       = "0xffffffffc0c13080"
    __ksymtab_gpl       = "0xffffffffc0c13030"
    __ksymtab_strings   = "0xffffffffc0caeb78"
    __mcount_loc        = "0xffffffffc0ca8530"
    __param             = "0xffffffffc0cae538"
    __tracepoints_ptrs  = "0xffffffffc0caebd0"
    __tracepoints_strings= "0xffffffffc0caed90"
    __tracepoints       = "0xffffffffc0cbcea0"
    _ftrace_events      = "0xffffffffc0cbba10"
```

The only relevant topic I could find was this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236359 -- but no solution in there. I've kept my system up to date. Running Arch Linux with i3 as window manager. My kernel is 4.14.52-1-lts. Any thoughts what could be the cause of this?

Comment: That graphic card has been historically problematic try new versions of the Intel drivers. Do you still have the same problem without the mouse?

Comment: You refer to these drivers? https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xf86-video-intel/ -- I'll install and see what happens. The problems occur both when suspending and when the screen goes black due to inactivity and I try move the mouse indeed.

Comment: You can try removing the intel driver and using [native modesetting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Installation).

Comment: @jasonwryan native modesetting does not support external monitors in some cases.

Comment: Man oh man I hope the solution is as simple as installing `xf86-video-intel`... this is driving me crazy on my brand new laptop